# Thymeleaf: How to use OR operator for th:class?

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

For example:

```
    <section class="sidebar">
      <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li th:class="${selectedType} == 'daily-report' OR {selectedType} == 'monthly-report'? 'active'">
  <!-- <li class="active"> -->
            <a href="/reports"><span>Reports</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

I want to set the li class to `active` when the `selectedType` either is `daily-report` or `monthly-report`. Can't find any example on the web. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the corrected syntax.

```
<section class="sidebar">
  <ul class="sidebar-menu">
    <li th:class="${(selectedType == 'daily-report' || selectedType == 'monthly-report') ? 'active' : ''}">
      <a href="/reports"><span>Reports</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```